# data filter not working html5 with php

Tags: php, html

Data filter not working according to data i have 3 three category in my database

only last product showing all other are missing . please help me .

```
 <ul class="portfolio-filter text-center">
            <li><a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter=".portfolio-item">All Template</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".personal">Personal</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".business">Business</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".ecommerce">Shopping</a></li>
        </ul><!--/#portfolio-filter-->

        <div class="row">
        <?php foreach($personal as $per){?>
            <div class="portfolio-items">
                <div class="portfolio-item <?php echo $per['category']; ?> col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <div class="recent-work-wrap">
                         <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url().$per['image'];?>" alt="">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                <h3><a href="<?php echo base_url('buynow/index/'.$per['id']); ?>">Checkout</a></h3>
                            <p><?php echo $per['name']; ?></p>
                            <a class="preview" href="<?php echo $per['demo_link']; ?>"  target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Demo</a>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                 <?php }?>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: are you fetching `$personal` correctly? Where is that code?

Comment: yes data showing perfectly once show all when page refresh after only show one product each filter